# What is `[..^3]` index? The Dot-Dot indexer?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-5

Reading an answer I found the following instruction :
`input[..^3]`

I found that `^` change the orientation of the index. From end.

Doing a basic test it seams to be a feature of .net5

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World"[^3]);    // The 3rd char starting from the end
//Console.WriteLine("Hello World"[.^3]); // Error Identifier expected, invalid syntax
Console.WriteLine("Hello World"[..^3]);  // Everything except the last 3, like a substring
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/elDmzh

And mean "Everything except the last 3, like a substring", but that didn't gave me much result in the MSDN.
What is this indexer name? Is it a SubString syntactic sugar?

Comment: This is called the range operation

Comment: [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

Comment: arg this gets asked 3 times a day

Comment: Yes! Knowing the name is the key. As ".." or "dotdot operator" are not the wisest keyword for a research.

Comment: @TheGeneral, get the man(me)  a duplicate link. I didn't get any thing from my search. And I understand why there is so mutch question about single operator like `?` and now `..`.

Comment: For strings, the syntax will call Substring. For Spans it will essentially call Slice. For Arrays it will create a new array consisting of the sub array defined by the range. Other types can accept Index and/or Range arguments and do what makes sense. For example List<T> only accepts Index and not Range